# Oscillation of a simple pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator, potential-energy, oscillators

What is maximum possible time period of oscillation of a simple pendulum on earth? Please elaborate your answers.

Comment: Do you mean the region, where gravity is still homogeneous? By "simple pendulum" you mean small oscillation and linear approximation? This is not a precise question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple pendulum performs simple harmonic motion when it is displaced very slightly. You can say that a simple pendulum performs a periodic motion which can be treated as simple harmonic motion in small oscillation

Now lets move forward supposing it to be pure SHM.

The time period of a simple pendulum does not depend on how much it is displaced( but it must be small enough so that motion can be treated as shm.
 Time period of a simple pendulum (T) is given by,
 $$T= 2\pi\sqrt{\frac lg}$$

Where l is length of pendulum and g is gravitational acceleration of earth. 
( Here g is considered to be constant as bob is treated to be near the earth surface.) 
So you can see that as you keep increasing the length of thread time period goes on increasing, so no limit.